# Assigning an enum property overwrites the NSArray* property below it

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, enums, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class with, amongst others, 2 properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIDeviceOrientation previousOrientation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* childBrowserUrlWhitelist;
```

When I create the array everything is fine:

```
self.childBrowserUrlWhitelist = @[@"myFirstValue", @"mySecondValue"];
```

At this point `_childBrowserUrlWhitelist` is pointing at a valid address with expected values in it.
Later on I assign the property `self.previousOrientation`

```
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    self.previousOrientation = orientation;
}
```

At the point where `self.previousOrientation` is assigned the value of `childBrowserUrlWhitelist` changes to point to an invalid location. As far as I can tell this would be caused by the assignment to `_previousOrientation` overflowing and trashing the pointer stored in `_childBrowserUrlWhitelist` but I have no idea why this would happen. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you use `@synthesize` statements?  If so, please show them.

Comment: No I have not used any @synthesize statements

Comment: Hmmm, that looks seriously broken then.  What version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: Compiler is set to "Apple LLVM 5.0", I am using Xcode 5.0.2. My workaround at the moment is just to move previousOrientation to an instance variable rather than a property but I would really like to get to the bottom of what is going on.

Comment: Something more insidious is happening here.  I think you should add a watchpoint to the object instance to check all write accesses to it.  I would imagine you have a stackoverflow or somesuch bug as the root cause.

Comment: So..erm...turns out I was trying to debug in release mode... nothing was getting overwritten by anything, and the crash I thought was caused by a trashed array pointer was something else entirely which because obvious when i switched back to debug builds... sorry...

Comment: Oh well, at least there was a happy ending :)

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, I'll remember to check the obvious things in future